# How to get UICollectionViewCell to size properly when using SwiftUI PreviewProvider

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, swiftui-previews

SwiftUI Previews are great and quickly allow us to preview views. I know its possible to create a wrapper to preview UIKit views, however I’m having trouble getting a CollectionViewCell preview to properly size it's height when using `.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)`. From my testing, the intrinsicContentSize height is always -1 and causes issues. Instead of fitting nicely, the preview takes up as much height as possible. How can I get this to fit properly? I’m already setting the content hugging priority in the wrapper but that doesn't seem to work. I think the issue has to do with the constraints.

Here are the current results:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.text = "First Label"

        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.text = "Second Label"

        let blue = UIView()
        blue.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        blue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, blue])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 5
        stack.alignment = .leading
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.trailingAnchor),
            
            blue.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            blue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


struct UIViewPreview<View: UIView>: UIViewRepresentable {
    let view: View
    
    init(_ builder: @escaping () -> View) {
        view = builder()
    }
    
    // MARK: UIViewRepresentable
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) {
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    }
}

struct MyCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UIViewPreview {
            MyCell()
        }
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        .frame(width: 400)
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is a SwiftUI example of what I’m looking for:

```
struct SwiftUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
            Text("Label 1")
            Text("Label 2")
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "[LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing.". We can't do that for UICollectionViewCell, because it is layouted by autoresizing mask to external container - in this case all available space.

Comment: I figured it might be something like that. Thanks for the confirmation.